# How to call an exe multiple times with 2 arguments (1 needs to be modified each time)

Tags: python, image, executable

I'm trying to write a python program that will take in a directory that holds a bunch of images, then runs an exe on that image and places it into a new directory. On the command line, the exe works by calling ./exe arg1 arg2. Arg1 is the source image, and arg2 is the name of the new output image that should be placed in a new directory. Here's what I have so far:

```
image_files = glob.glob('path/to/source/dir')
output_directory = 'path/to/output/dir'
for image in image_files:
    # run through exe
    subprocess.run(['exe', image, output_directory])
```

I'm also getting an error when running the program that says 'no such file or directory: 'exe'' when I have the exe in the same folder as my python script. The exe does not have the extension .exe, however. Any help on this?

Comment: Could you specify OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the extension and the `./`:

`subprocess.run(['./myfile.exe', image, output_directory])`

If it's still not working, use os.getcwd() to check that it's actually the same directory python is working from.